# Calling .net server data in PHP server

Tags: php, .net, sql-server

We are using PHP server for our website. The organisation internal server is maintained in .net server that is unregistered.

How to access .net server data(database) in the PHP server?

Comment: What DBMS you are using in your .NET project?

Comment: What database are we talking about? MSSQL?

Comment: You could try google: "connect to xxx database in PHP"?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get .net server data(database) in php server. Is it possilbe?

There are multiple possibilities:

- access data through REST webservices
- access data through database connection if the .NET data server (SQL server) is accessible through a connection string